# C#: How to use regex to match string '@A=1, @B=2, @C=3, ....."

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string something like this.

@A1=1,@B1=2,@C1=3,@D2=4123,@D3='asdsd',...

The string length is undefined.

How to use Regex to get the values each variable name?

Expect result is

A1 is 1

B1 is 2

C1 is 3

Here is my initial code, but that seems not working.

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@"((@[\w]+=('.+'|[\d\.]+),?)+?)+");
GroupCollection gc = exp.Match(strArg).Groups;
```

Comment: How to show `@D3='asdsd'`? Is there any `,` in parameters?

Comment: Try using split instead~

Comment: Is is possible for one of the values to contain an `@` characters? If so, your input does not meet the specification for a 'regular' string, and  you'll have a hard time getting a good expression to match your values, even if it is technically possible in most modern regex engines. Additionally, these look like parameters in an sql string, and if that's what you have here you're going about this the whole wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

```
string txt = @"@A1=1,@B1=2,@C1=3,@D2=4123,@D3='asdsd'";
string patten = @"@([^=]*)=([^,]*)";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(txt, patten))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is {1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value));
}
```

This is an example

Answer (score 0):

**A Group is *only* created *once* for each grouping `(..)` construct** - this is *independent* of how many times a group is actually 'repeated' (eg. with `+`) to match the input in the `Regex#Match` call.

To solve this directly with regular expression either -

- Use a "global match" ([`Regex#Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx)), remove the repeat-group modifiers in the regular expression, and let the re-application of the regex find each group (this yields a *collection* of match results, each with the same set of groups); or
- Create a hard-coded group for *each* of the @letter.. constructs manually. (This only works for a fixed set of fields and can quickly become unwieldy, however.)

Alternatively, if possible -

- Simplify the problem with a `String#Split` (or `Regex#Split`) first and then process resulting part sequence.

---

Wrt "seems not working" there are several immediate issues, ignoring the afore mentioned grouping problem, other concerns and brought up by Joel in a comment -

- The regular expression does not take spaces after a `,` into account (maybe this is just an error in the title?)
- Multiple strings will trivially break it because `'.+'` is greedy and will "eat up" some of the parameter pairs

Without the *actual* input and the *actual* "doesn't work" data it is
   hard to further reason/explain it; in any case these two issues can be addressed - fsvo - at the same time as implementing the "global match" approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regular expression I quickly whipped up. It won't support commas in quotes though.

```
@(\w+)=(.*?)(?:,|$)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uJ5bB5/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
@([^=]*)\s*=\s*(.*?)(?=,|$)
```

You can simply try this.See demo.Grab the groups.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/19